# How do I time a modal pop up?

Tags: asp.net, modal-dialog, modalpopups

I have a function that does some database update in asp.net. I'd like a modal popup to show a "success" message for just 5 seconds after my function has been called. In this case, the modal popup would not be triggered by any "TargetControl" but would show up for just 5 seconds once the function is done.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking the AjaxControlToolkit Modal Popup.

Comment: How long would the "failure" message popup duration be?

Comment: @Brian - Yes, I am referring to the AjaxControlToolkit Modal Popup.

Answer (score 0):

You can't close standard javascript modal dialogs (alert, confirm,..) after a timeout. Only manual close works with them.

But, you can use [***jquery/UI dialog***](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/):

```
// timeOut in ms
function showMessageWithTiemout(message, timeOut){

    // show dialog
    var successDialog = $('<div>'+message+'</div>').dialog({modal: true});  

    //close it after 5 seconds
    setTimeout(function(){ successDialog.dialog('close'); }, timeOut);

}

//usage:
showMessageWithTiemout('success!', 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually call the show method on the panel like:

```
var pnl = $find("<%= modal.ClientID");
pnl.show();
```

So you can use window.setTimeout to call this:

```
window.setTimeout(function() { /* code */ }, 5000);
```

But it can't just *happen* very easily.

HTH.